# No sound with X-Fi USB Sound Card after Supend

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa

I use a USB Sound Card (Creative X-Fi Surround 5.1 Pro, which I purchased in 2008). It works fine on my Ubuntu 23.10 until I suspend my PC. After resume, media playback and sound are not working until I remove the sound card and plug it back in. I found a few posts about sound issues after suspend but didn't manage to solve the issue yet. Coming from Windows I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

Comment: Find out which driver is used! Remove it via `sudo modprobe -r xyzdriver, go to sleep, wake up and insert it again `sudoe modprobe xyzdriver`. (Replace "xyzdriver" with the driver you have figured out) Report back if that works.